# #1064 error Mysql - PHPmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error

`` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NULL , `MaxTemp` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `MinTemp` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `MinRH` DOUBLE' at line 1 ``

Code:

`` CREATE TABLE `dbweat`.`Stations` ( `StationId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `StationName` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL , `EToin` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `MaxTemp` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `MinTemp` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `MinRH` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `SolarRad` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `RainFall` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `Wind4am` DOUBLE(5) NULL , `Wind4pm` DOUBLE(5) NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`StationId`)) ENGINE = InnoDB; ``

Comment: You require to provide decimal places on DOUBLE ie `DOUBLE(5,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same error several times.

When you define a DOUBLE field, you must specify both total number of digits (T) and number of digits after the decimal period (D). SO you use DOUBLE(T,D)

Instead of

```
DOUBLE(5)
```

use

```
DOUBLE(5,0)
```

However that will not give you any decimals. You may want to do DOUBLE(6,2) which gives 6 digits, two of which are decimals (1234.56)

If you want to store numbers between 0 and 1 with 5 decimal places precision you would do DOUBLE(5,5) for 0.12345

I hope that makes sense. Good luck.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html